# weex module weed-components use error

Tags: weex

We use weex install project.import weed-components module. How to import weed-components?

[image]

Current error message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're using vue syntax, but weex-components isn't compatible for vue syntax.

how to import custom components in vue syntax:

```js
  export default {
    components: {
      button: require('./button.vue'), //your custom component

    }
   ...
```